# Updating a YAML file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, yaml

My class is:

```
class Mycfg
    @@options = {}

    def init
        @@options = YAML.load_file(Dir.pwd + PATH)
    end

    def set(key, val)
        @@options[key] = val
    end

    def get(key)
        @@options[key]
    end

    def save
    end
end
```

Using this class:

```
oj = Mycfg.new
oj.init

if oj.get 'name' == 'tom'
   oj.set 'changed', Data.now
end

oj.save
```

YAML file:

```
name : tom
pawd : 123456
version : 0.0.1
created : 2011-10-24
changed : 2011-10-24
```

How to I finish the method `save` to update the YAML file if something has changed?

Comment: You should cache the original value of the hash. Then at the end of the program check if it equals the current @@options. If so then erase the old yaml file and have ruby write out the hash to_yaml from scratch. If you want to see this as an example, I would gladly oblige.

Comment: We could add a @@copy_options for this class to cache the changed, the point is i don't know how to save the data to the yaml file.

Answer (score 11):

It's a one liner.

The `w+` truncates the file to 0-length and writes as if it's a new file.

`options_hash` is current value of `@@options`.

You will need a getter/accessor to retrieve the full hash. If you made `@@options` an instance variable instead of a class variable you could simply do a `attr_accessor :options` and then retrieve it with `oj.options`.

```
File.open(Dir.pwd + PATH, 'w+') {|f| f.write(options_hash.to_yaml) }
```

Comment: `File.open(Dir.pwd + PATH, 'w+') {|f| f.write(YAML::dump(@@options)) }`
it works to me, and it cannot finds the `options_hash`